# Module not found when using vim activitywatch plugin with python pip dependency while in virtualenv for project

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, vim-plugin

while I'm in a virtualenv, my [aw-watcher](https://github.com/ActivityWatch/aw-watcher-vim) plugin doesn't work properly. It has a dependency on a pip installed package `aw-core` which it cannot find while in the virtualenv.
How would the vim plugin need to be changed so that it defines this dependency not as it does right now but instead bundles it or explicitly refers to the global pip installed packages instead of the virtualenv?

Comment: Have you already installed `aw-core` into the virtualenv?

Comment: No, virtualenvs are meant to encapsulate the current working context. My global vim plugin shouldn't be dependent on my current environment.